# Google Sheets - Change row color once multiple boxes are checked

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, colors, row, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I would like each row to turn green, once two of the checkboxes (in Columns F and G) are checked for that row.

I have tried using conditional formatting with the following formulas applied to range `A2:I145`:

```
=IF($F2=TRUE,1)=AND($G2=TRUE,1)  /* This colors the row when cells are unchecked */

=IF($F2:$G2=TRUE) /* This does not color the row at all */
```

I know that if it was only based on one checkbox, it could be accomplished with `=$F2=TRUE`. There is documentation on this [here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-checkbox/), but they don't give an example with requirement of two checkboxes.

Is there a simple function that can perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One TRUE value is treated as 1, which is why two TRUE values sum up to 2. You just need to check your cells against equating to 2. Please see a picture below; of range A1:A5 only A2 gets colored since only B2+C2 result in 2.

[image]

Comment: This works! With your method in mind, I am now using `=($F2+$G2)=2` to color the entire row. One thing I noticed, which may help others: Conditional Formatting is a hierarchy. So I also had to make sure this was listed higher on the list than other functions which might conflict.

Comment: Good stuff. For someone else's reference, if applying the same thing to my example, that would be =($B:$B+$C:$C)=2, and the range must be set for A1:C5